# How to validate the html input box for the number with the length of 6 in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to insert insert the fix length otp type number in the input box , if i set the input type **text** then it takes the all charactor along with the numbers.

and in other case if i set the input type **number** the it takes only number but the one issue comes with that the length of the otp is not fixed, i am doing this in react js, now i am stucked that how i can create an html input tag type of number which only takes the 6 digits only.

i need that solution , how we can have the input box type of number who takes the 6 length string in the input in react js

Comment: When do you want to perform validation?

Comment: i just need a input box which takes only numbers in input with the fix length of 6.